# Define bubble sizes according to a column and bubble colors according to another column in scatter plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm building a simple scatter plot that reads data from a xls file. 
It's the classic Life expectancy x GDP per capita scatter plot. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

#ler a terceira sheet da planilha
data = pd.read_excel('sample.xls', sheet_name=0)
data.head()

plt.scatter(x = data['LifeExpec'],
        y = data['GDPperCapita'],
        s = data['PopX1000'],
        c = data['PopX1000'],
        cmap=cm.viridis,
        edgecolors = 'none',
        alpha = 0.7)

for estado in range(len(data['UF'])):
    plt.text(x = data['LifeExpec'][estado],
         y = data['GDPperCapita'][estado],
         s = data['UF'][estado],
         fontsize = 14)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The .xls file:
[image]

The population column from the xls file (PopX1000) is defining the bubbles sizes and currently it's defining their colors as well. 
I would like the bubbles to change sizes according to population (as they do now), but the colors to change according to the Region the State is in.

I believe I can't simply change the c property because it expects a float value.
Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform the `Region` to a numeric representation, and use that as a "key" to your colormap. Below are two methods to do that (one is commented out, pick whichever you choose, the result should be the same):

```
plt.scatter(x = data['LifeExpec'],
        y = data['GDPperCapita'],
        s = data['PopX1000'],
        c = pd.factorize(data['Region'])[0],
        # Alternatively:
        # c = data['Region'].astype('category').cat.codes
        cmap=cm.viridis,
        edgecolors = 'none',
        alpha = 0.7)
```